# Convert System.Object[] and dereference properties

Tags: powershell, scripting, azure-cli

Azure CLI returns System.Object[] which aren't handy to work with. For example I can create an App-Insights with a script and az cli returns a System.Object[] including the instrumentation key. I can write methods to iterate over the array and extract the required fields, but there must be an easier way

I tried to convert the object to different formats but I couldn't find a possibility to convert the result of an cli command to an object with dereferencable properties

```
$a = az monitor app-insights component show -a myfuntions -g my-group
$a

{
  "appId": "<id>",
  "applicationId": "myfunctions",
  "applicationType": "web",
  "creationDate": "2019-05-17T15:22:05.042607+00:00",
  "etag": "\"8000ece5-0000-0200-0000-4edfe57e0000\"",
  "flowType": "Bluefield",
  "hockeyAppId": null,
  "hockeyAppToken": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/1111111-4d7d-4df4-8dae-5311111111/resourceGroups/dev-api/providers/microsoft.insights/components/dev-validierung-functions"
  "instrumentationKey": "3232323-23e05-32da-bf03-a8b8b4d18783",
  "kind": "web",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "name": "myfunctions",
  "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
  "requestSource": "rest",
  "resourceGroup": "mygroup",
  "samplingPercentage": null,
  "tags": {},
  "tenantId": "<the tenant id>",
  "type": "microsoft.insights/components"
}
```

The var $a contains the System.Object[]. It's possible to iterate over all objects in the array in a self-defined function, but I think I'm missing some detail. There must be an easy way to convert into dereferencable objects.

Comment: Base on the output I'd say `$a` contains a json object. What you want to do? Iterate over all properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PsObject` property:

```
$object = @"
{
"appId": "<id>",
"applicationId": "myfunctions",
"applicationType": "web",
"creationDate": "2019-05-17T15:22:05.042607+00:00",
"etag": "\"8000ece5-0000-0200-0000-4edfe57e0000\"",
"flowType": "Bluefield",
"hockeyAppId": null,
"hockeyAppToken": null,
"id": "/subscriptions/1111111-4d7d-4df4-8dae-5311111111/resourceGroups/dev-api/providers/microsoft.insights/components/dev-validierung-functions",
"instrumentationKey": "3232323-23e05-32da-bf03-a8b8b4d18783",
"kind": "web",
"location": "westeurope",
"name": "myfunctions",
"provisioningState": "Succeeded",
"requestSource": "rest",
"resourceGroup": "mygroup",
"samplingPercentage": null,
"tags": {},
"tenantId": "<the tenant id>",
"type": "microsoft.insights/components"
}
"@

$j = $object | ConvertFrom-Json
$j.PsObject.Properties | % { Write-Host "Name $($_.Name) ; Value $($_.Value)"}
```

Output:

```
Name appId ; Value <id>
Name applicationId ; Value myfunctions
Name applicationType ; Value web
Name creationDate ; Value 2019-05-17T15:22:05.042607+00:00
Name etag ; Value "8000ece5-0000-0200-0000-4edfe57e0000"
Name flowType ; Value Bluefield
Name hockeyAppId ; Value
Name hockeyAppToken ; Value
Name id ; Value /subscriptions/1111111-4d7d-4df4-8dae-5311111111/resourceGroups/dev-api/providers/microsoft.insights/components/dev-validierung-functions
Name instrumentationKey ; Value 3232323-23e05-32da-bf03-a8b8b4d18783
Name kind ; Value web
Name location ; Value westeurope
Name name ; Value myfunctions
Name provisioningState ; Value Succeeded
Name requestSource ; Value rest
Name resourceGroup ; Value mygroup
Name samplingPercentage ; Value
Name tags ; Value
Name tenantId ; Value <the tenant id>
Name type ; Value microsoft.insights/components
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, I see. I also noticed the ConvertFrom-Json method, but I used it wrong I guess.

I wrote

`$b = ConvertFrom-Json $a` 

which didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Convert it from json.

```
$obj = $a | convertfrom-json
```